# Do any of the currency exchanges at Incheon International Airport deal in Turkish lira?

Tags: exchange, turkey, south-korea, icn

I'm about to fly from Istanbul to Seoul and I have a useful amount of Turkish Lira (`TRY`) left but I don't have any South Korean Won (`KRW`) to pay for the metro to my hostel when I get there.

Several times in the past I've ended up being stuck with currencies that are very difficult to exchange in the country I've arrived in.

**Can I sell `TRY` at the airport in Seoul?**

<sup>(I've also asked [the reciprocal of this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9535/do-any-of-the-currency-exchanges-at-istanbul-ataturk-airport-deal-in-korean-won), since Stack Exchange questions are meant more for the long tail than just for the original asker.)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be **No**.

None of the currency exchange counters listed Turkish Lira on their boards but I didn't ask either since the rate for US dollars was reasonable I decided to go with [SigueSigueBen's advice in the converse question I also asked](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/9545/140).