# Do any of the currency exchanges at Istanbul Atatürk Airport deal in Korean won?

Tags: exchange, turkey, south-korea, isl

I'm about to fly from Istanbul to Seoul and I have a useful amount of Turkish Lira (`TRY`) left but I don't have any South Korean Won (`KRW`) to pay for the metro to my hostel when I get there.

Several times in the past I've ended up being stuck with currencies that are very difficult to exchange in the country I've arrived in.

**Can I buy `KRW` at the airport in Istanbul?**

<sup>(I've also asked [the reciprocal of this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9534/do-any-of-the-currency-exchanges-at-incheon-international-airport-deal-in-turkis), since Stack Exchange questions are meant more for the long tail than just for the original asker.)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be **No**.

None of the currency exchange counters listed Korean Won on their boards but I didn't ask either since the rate for US dollars was reasonable I decided to go with [SigueSigueBen's advice here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/9545/140).

By the way, all of the change counters I could find charge 4% commission though they don't all announce it equally prominently.

Answer (score 5):

Money exchange in Turkey has traditionally been so prevalent due to the instability of the lira that the cost of exchanging US dollars and Euros is almost negligible. However, most other currencies are bought and sold at a considerable margin, so even if someone will exchange lira and won, it will be to your disadvantage.

Your best course of action is to exchange your Turkish lira into USD at an exchange bureau in Istanbul (do this in the city, not the airport), and then exchange this into Korean won once you arrive in Korea.